# ¿Son equivalentes "¡qué + adjetivo/nombre que!" y "¡cómo+ adjetivo/nombre que"

Tags: gramática, locuciones

> El lunes invitamos a Josefina a la reunión, pero no quiso venir con nosotros.
>   — ¡**Qué raro** que no quisiese salir! Es sociable.

Me gustaría saber si es similar a la frase:

> El lunes invitamos a Josefina a la reunión, pero no quiso venir con nosotros.
>   —¡**Cómo raro** que no quisiese salir! Es sociable.

Comment: "cómo raro" no es gramatical. Sería bueno que indicaras la fuente (¿google translate?)

Comment: @Gustavson, la forma gramatical de la segunda frase es comun en Argentina

Comment: Soy argentino y "cómo raro" NO es gramatical y NO se usa en ningún caso como exclamación. Debés estar confundido con "¿cómo "raro"?

Answer (score 1):

Sólo es gramatical decir:

(A) El lunes invitamos a Josefina a la reunión, pero no quiso venir con nosotros.

(B) ¡**Qué raro** que no quisiese salir! Es sociable.

El único caso en que podría usarse "cómo" es para refutar o cuestionar el comentario del otro:

(A) El lunes invitamos a Josefina a la reunión, pero no quiso venir con nosotros. Es raro que no quisiese salir.

(B) ¿Cómo "raro que no quisiese salir"? Es re antisociable.

"cómo" sólo puede utilizarse delante de adjetivos y adverbios como equivalente del "how" inglés en frases con "de", y por lo general con un verbo copulativo:

(A) Es muy sociable.

(B) ¿Cómo (es) de sociable? (¿hasta qué punto / en qué medida?)

También existe la forma:

(B) ¿Cuán sociable? (muy poco usada por ser excesivamente formal)

Answer (score -1):

**Significan lo mismo.** Las dos frases son funcionalmente equivalentes.

El uso de la segunda forma —aunque gramaticalmente incorrecta—, es común en el habla de algunas regiones, por lo que podría ser un texto que recogiese ese modo corriente en Argentina

Comment: ¿se puede saber por qué esta respuesta fue votada negativamente?